# understanding guardian.shortcuts.get_objects_for_user

Tags: python, django, django-guardian

I have trouble understanding the behavior of the django-guardian function get_objects_for_user. I am assigning group object permissions, but those permissions do not seem to exist for get_objects_for_user.

```
>>> u = User.objects.get(username='angus')
>>> u.has_perm('news.change_news', n)
True
>>> from guardian.shortcuts import get_objects_for_user
>>> get_objects_for_user(u, (u'news.change_news', ))
[]
>>> get_objects_for_user(u, ('change_news'), klass=News)
[]
```

The documentation seems quite clear, though:

```
get_objects_for_user: (user, perms, klass=None, use_groups=True, any_perm=False)
Returns queryset of objects for which a given ``user`` has *all*
permissions present at ``perms``.
```

I do not know even where to start debugging. Any suggestions?

Update:

My model is defined as follows:

```
class News(models.Model):
    departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department, blank=True, related_name='news', through='NewsDepartmentMembership')
    research_groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True, related_name='news', through='NewsGroupMembership')
    people_involved = models.ManyToManyField(Person, blank=True, related_name='news')
    related_news = models.ManyToManyField('News', blank=True)

    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('Slug'), unique_for_date='pub_date',)
    excerpt = models.TextField(_('Excerpt'), blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(_('Content'), blank=True)

    is_published = models.BooleanField(_('Published'), default=False)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Publication date'), default=datetime.datetime.now)
    is_feat = models.BooleanField(_('Featured'), default=False)

    published = PublishedNewsManager()
    objects = models.Manager()
    featured = FeaturedNewsManager()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this:
news = get_objects_for_user(u, ('change_news'), klass=News)

Edit:
Well, its easy to figure out where the problem is : try using guardian.shortcuts.get_perms (http://pythonhosted.org/django-guardian/api/guardian.shortcuts.html#get-perms) to see if permission between user and object really exists. I ran into similar issue some time ago and if i remember correctly, then it had something to do with user beeing superuser. Try setting is_superuser false for the user and see if has_perm still returns true.

Also, if possible, i suggest you don't use get_objects_for_user shortcut when project gets bigger. Its *VERY* slow query once you get more objects/permissions in the database.

Alan

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't work. It's weird, I am using this function with other classes of my application without problem :-/

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb I'm guessing you're referring to (your?) github issue https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian/issues/189 here when you say that the shortcut is very slow. Any suggestion what to use instead of get_objects_by_user?

Comment: @TauPan The question and pr are almost 5 years old now. django-guardian is live and used project and they have improved their speed.

I do not remember the problem i had nor have enough information about how things are working right now.

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb Yeah sorry for reviving this undead question. Unfortunately the performance problems are still present and I would have appreciated if you still remembered what you did to alleviate any performance problems you mentioned.I'll try to improve the performance for our use-case and see if I can come  up with an acceptable PR.

Comment: @TauPan Permissions are very complex issue and not just from the relations & database point. I would even go as far as saying that permissions are mostly ux issue. And the need for too many permissions should probably warrant review of whole permission system. 

If i remember correctly, then our case was that we needed to do a lot of permission checks in different stages of returning a view: View level, template level and even in js. so what we did was we wrote our own query to get the permissions from database and then cached the results per view. And then ran our checks against cache